# TruncDay not working in Django+MySQL5.5

Tags: python, mysql, django

Lets create a small Django app with this model:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now lets try to get a truncated version of this date:

```
Thing.objects.create()

print Thing.objects.annotate(
    truncstamp=TruncDay('timestamp')
).values('truncstamp')
```

If we just run the queryset in Django, we get an error which might explain something:

```
ValueError: Database returned an invalid datetime value. Are time zone definitions for your database and pytz installed?
```

But I have pytz installed, and I've loaded the time zones in my database.  I mean, this query works:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'SYSTEM', 'UTC');
```

Lets see what query it's trying to run:

```
print Thing.objects.annotate(
    truncstamp=TruncDay('timestamp')
).values('truncstamp').query
```

This yields the query:

```
SELECT CAST(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(`stuff_thing`.`timestamp`, 'UTC', UTC), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AS DATETIME) AS `truncstamp` FROM `stuff_thing`
```

If I try to run this query in MySQL it doesn't work.

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'UTC' in 'field list'
```

Here's the minimum subset of the query that still gives the same same error:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(timestamp, 'UTC', UTC) from stuff_thing;
```

What are we doing here?  Converting from UTC to UTC?  Why is the second UTC not quoted?  Is Django emitting invalid SQL?  Even if you do quote the second 'UTC', all you get from the conversion is NULL.  Why is it even trying to convert from UTC to UTC though?  Can't we skip that step?

This is a freshly generated app with default settings.  I noticed that if I comment out this default setting, the query will run:

```
# TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
```

Now the results come back with the America/Chicago time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Oh.  Wonderful.  I guess MySQL caches queries, and the cache is case-sensitive.  Behold this insanity:

```
mysql> SELECT CAST(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(`stuff_thing`.`timestamp`, 'UTC', 'UTC'), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AS DATETIME) AS `truncstamp` FROM `stuff_thing` LIMIT 21;
+------------+
| truncstamp |
+------------+
| NULL       |
| NULL       |
+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CAST(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(`stuff_thing`.`timestamp`, 'UTC', 'UTC'), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AS DATETIME) as `truncstamp` FROM `stuff_thing` LIMIT 21;
+---------------------+
| truncstamp          |
+---------------------+
| 2016-11-15 00:00:00 |
| 2016-11-15 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I restarted mysql and now both queries work.  I suppose it was broken since I imported the time zones without restarting it.